# How to get he Shape of AfineTransform rotated Image in Java

Tags: java, image, rotation, shapes

I am able to rotate an image. This works great. However, I want to be able to extraxt the Shape/Polygon of the result image so that I can use it to capture a mouse event when the mouse moves over the rotated image.

Her'es my code:

```
private Shape imageShape;

private Image rotateFilter(Image img, int degrees) {
    BufferedImage sourceImage = (BufferedImage)img;

    double radians = Math.toRadians(degrees);
    double cos = Math.abs(Math.cos(radians));
    double sin = Math.abs(Math.sin(radians));

    int width = sourceImage.getWidth();
    int height = sourceImage.getHeight();

    int w = (int) Math.floor(width * cos + height * sin);
    int h = (int) Math.floor(width * sin + height * cos);

    int x = (w - width) / 2;
    int y = (h - height) / 2;

    BufferedImage destImage = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);        
    Graphics2D g2d = destImage.createGraphics();

    AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
    at.rotate(radians, x + (width / 2), y + (height / 2));
    at.translate(x, y);
```

**somehow get the Shape/Polygon here (imageShape)**
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BICUBIC);
        g2d.drawRenderedImage(sourceImage, at);
        g2d.dispose();
        return destImage;
    }

```
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    int mx = e.getX();
    int my = e.getY();
    return imageShape.contains(mx, my);
}
```

Comment: Why this interface broke up my code, I dont know.

Comment: You could simply create a polygon with your original image boundaries and then apply the transformation to the polygon too.

Comment: Does the BufferedImage have any Transforms? I don't thnk so. Does the AffineTransform apply to any BufferedImages? I don't see anything - so do what this other guy said

Answer (score 0):

Yeah unfortunately there is no easy way. If you rotate the image you still get a rectangle with the image rotated on to it. The only way I have been able to get around it is to manage the 4 corners using maths but of course the maths is never exactly the same as AffineTransform rotate.

What I want to do is rotate the image and apply a shape to it so that I can use contains() with the mouse x/y. I only want the mouse to receive events when the mouse is actuall over the image, even if it is rotated.

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to do this - other than the direct math you proposed which you have to apply to the transformation matrix as well to be on the same side:

a) use points and transform these:

```
    AffineTransform at=AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(....);
    Point p=new Point(x, y);
    at.transform(p, p);
```

This will transform the point p and store the result onto itself, so p will change - you can use another point to store the new coordinates.

Apply to the four points then create the Polygon

```
Polygon pl=new Polygon();
for(i=0; i<points.length; i+++) pl.addPoint(points[i].x, points[i].y);
```

Polygon has the contains() method.

b) create the Polygon (or Rectangle) from the original image

```
Polygon pl=new Polygon();
pl.addPoint(0, 0);
pl.addPoint(im.getWidth()-1, 0);
pl.addPoint(im.getWidth()-1, im.getHeight()-1);
pl.addPoint(0, im.getHeight()-1);
```

or

```
Rectangle r=new Rectangle(0, 0, im.getWidth(), im.getHeight());
```

Then use

```
  AffineTransform at=new AffineTransform(.....);
  Shape sh=at.createTransformedShape(pl);
```

and have sh as the new shape. This thing doesn't always work accurately (I mean the whole thing with shapes, bounds etc) but is convenient if you are looking for that.

Comment: Yes, I have used your Optiob B almost exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have used your Option B almost exactly. The way I did this was to store two rectangles. One to store the x,y,w,h of the rotated/transformed image and another to store a set of the original image x,y,w,h. The latter rectangle doesn't change (well, at least until I zoom, in which case this rect is updated). Since the latter doesnt change I use that to keep a note of the 'real' image rect not the transformed one. So what I do us affineTransform the image then build a polygon exactly like you suggest and then use createTrasformedShape to get me the shape. So spot on the nail. It works really well. A tad slow but remarkably accurate. Thanks.